# how include the same shared js file in many rails app?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

I have a personal JS lib call `foo.js.coffee`

I have 2 (or more) app in rails 5

I want include this js file in each app, but when I update this JS file, I don't want to copy the new version in each other rails app, so : **how can we shared JS file between any rails app?**

Comment: Easy. Make it a gem. Host it on a private platform like Gemfury. Include in your app Gemfile. Done.

Comment: If you are using NPM for JS package management, you could also host it on a private NPM account and include it in your `package.json`.

Comment: your solutions d'ont update file for each projects. It need to update version at each change... with `bundle update` for rails for exemple... it's not what I need... Make a symlink can work?